# Fixing issue with Visual studio 2017 - TFS not able to connect to server - error tf30063

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Issue:- TF30063: You are not authorized to access "ProjectSolution"
I had faced the above issue after changing my account credentials and i was not able to connect to TFS.

Comment: If you going to answer your own question please put the solution as an answer on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I was able to resolve the above issue by following below steps which worked fine for me :-

1. Check if your account credentials are updated in Windows Credential Manager
2. Try opening the TFS link on Internet Explorer 32 bit which will prompt you for a login to your TFS account. Once you update/login with the new credentials, ensure your TFS page loads up on the browser. Restart Visual Studio and you should be able to connect back to TFS.

Note: Somehow the Internet Explorer 32 bit is interlinked with your VisualStudio's web browser and TFS. So ensure to open the 32bit IE even if you are running a 64 bit windows machine.

Comment: As the issue was resolved. You could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.